# Как добавить полоску между пунктами меню?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как добавить полоску разделяющую блоки меню?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если делать бордером, то получается на всю ширину элемента.

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 14pt;
  float: left;
  padding: 11px;
  color: #898989;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
  color: #0c7ff6;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:last-of-type {
  float: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar ">
      <a href="#">Главная </a>
      <a href="#">Сотрудничество </a>
      <a href="#">Гарантия</a>
      <a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a>
      <a href="#">Новости</a>
      <a href="#">Контакты</a>
      <a href="#">Заказать звонок</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Псевдоэлементом `::before` и селектором `+`.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

a + a {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

a + a:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: calc(-1em - 4px);
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте линию с помощью `:before` :

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,900');
*{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.navbar{
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}
nav a{
    font-size: 14pt;
    float:left;
    padding: 11px;
    color: #898989;
}

/*добавляем разделяющую полосу*/
nav a+a{
    position:relative;
}
nav a+a:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height:15px;
    width:1px;
    background-color:#999;
    display:block;
    left:0;
    top:17px;
}
nav a:last-child:before{
    display:none;
}

nav a:hover,nav a:active{
    color:#0c7ff6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:last-of-type{
    float:right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar ">
                <a href="#">Главная </a>
                <a href="#">Сотрудничество </a>
                <a href="#">Гарантия</a>
                <a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a>
                <a href="#">Новости</a>
                <a href="#">Контакты</a>
                <a href="#">Заказать звонок</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```